# How to refactor a loop with iterator. (Returning from closure)

Tags: rust, functional-programming

I want to refactor a function and use an iterator rather than a for loop. I have exemplified the problem with the following demo code to be refactored:

```
fn with_loop() -> bool {
    let foo = [1, 2, 25, 4, 5];
    let mut sum = 0;
    for bar in foo {
        if bar > 20 {return false;}
        sum += bar;
    }
    sum > 10
}
```

I want to do something like the following, the problem is I cannot return from a closure of course.

```
fn functional_programming() -> bool {
    let foo = [1, 2, 25, 4, 5];
    let sum: i32 = foo
        .into_iter()
        .inspect(|bar_ptr| {
            if *bar_ptr > 20 {
                // functional_programming() returns false;
                print!("I want to return false");
            }
        })
        .sum();
    sum > 10
}
```

Some extra constraints which I would prefer not to negotiate:

1. Scanning the iterable just once
2. Avoid collecting and reopening the iterator
3. Avoid too much nesting in the callbacks

Comment: Worth noting that `bar_ptr` is not a pointer, it is a reference. Rust does have pointers, and they are treated differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"[`sum()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) can be used to sum any type implementing `Sum`, including `Option` and `Result`."*

```rust
fn functional_programming() -> bool {
    let foo = [1, 2, 25, 4, 5];
    let sum = foo
        .iter()
        .map(|i| if *i > 20 { Err(()) } else { Ok(*i) })
        .sum::<Result<i64, _>>();
    let Ok(sum) = sum else {
        return false;
    };
    sum > 10
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5d50dd14cdd7c1b78cee1854bd5b443d)

Comment: Is best case complexity of this O(1) or O(iterable length)?

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza O(until_first_err).

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't the natural choice be `Option` if the error variant is `()`?

Comment: `foo.iter().map(|i| if *i > 20 { None } else { Some(*i) }).sum::<Option<i64>>().map(|s| s > 10).unwrap_or(false)`

Comment: @cafce25 `Option` would only return `None` if _all_ the values were `None`. Otherwise it returns the sum of the `Some (_)` values. OTOH `Result` returns `Err` as soon as _at least one_ of the values is `Err`.

Comment: @Jmb, no [`Sum for Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Sum%3COption%3CU%3E%3E-for-Option%3CT%3E) also states *"if it is a `None`, no further elements are taken, and the `None` is returned"* and that's also what I got from testing. i.e. `Option<T>` behaves the same as `Result<T, ()>`

Answer (score 1):

IMHO is [ControlFlow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.ControlFlow.html#method.map_continue) much better suited:

```
fn functional_programming() -> bool {
    let foo = [1, 2, 25, 4, 5];
    let ControlFlow::Continue(sum) = foo.iter().try_fold(0, |sum, &bar| {
        if bar > 20 {
            return ControlFlow::Break(sum);
        }
        ControlFlow::Continue(sum + bar)
    }) else { return false; };
    sum > 10
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be5752c34adb518ce0a2d2445f50822f)

Comment: Nice solution! Note: `ControlFlow` only works on Rust nightly at the moment.

Comment: @aedm Although this is true for some interesting new features to get the Break and Contiune values without `match`, [ControllFlow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.ControlFlow.html#method.map_continue) works in stable rust, as you can prove on [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be5752c34adb518ce0a2d2445f50822f).